# Evitar que submit actualice parte de una pagina

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo un html con el siguiente código:

```js
function mostrar() {
  var x = document.getElementById('alerta');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
#alerta {
  margin-top: 1 0px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="alerta">
    <a href="Start.htm">aparece con el  submit MANUAL</a><br>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="MANUAL">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" value="MANUAL" onclick="mostrar()">
    <input type="hidden" name='"MANUAL"' size="20px" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name='"AUTOMATICO"' size="20px" value="0">
  </form>
</div>
<td width="144px" height="21px">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" value="AUTOMATICO">
    <input type="hidden" name='"AUTOMATICO"' size="20px" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name='"MANUAL"' size="20px" value="0">
  </form>
</td>
```

Que es lo que quiero:
Es el `href` Start.html solo  se muestre cuando presiono el submit "MANUAL" y que desaparezca solo cuando presiono el submit AUTOMATICO

Que es lo que sucede:
Debido a que la página completa esta configurada para actualizar cada segundo (Así debe trabajar), cuando presiono el submit MANUAL toda la  página refresca y el href aparece por un instante y desaparece.

¿Hay alguna  forma de "aislar" esa parte del  código  cuando presiono el `submit` MANUAL? y que solamente  se deje de mostrar cuando presiono el `submit` AUTOMATICO.

Comment: que intentas hacer??? si solo quieres actualizar una parte tienes que meter el boton dentro del form que quieres actualizar

Comment: Hola Critical Ghost, toda la página que tengo debe actualizarse cada segundo, sin embargo el div alerta en este caso debe ser estático y solo debe mostrarse en caso presione el botón MANUAL y dejar de mostrarse cuando presionó el botón AUTOMATICO, sin embargo con este código solo logro que se muestre por un segundo, esto debido al refresh de la pagina, hay alguna forma de aislar el div alerta para que esté no haga refresh con el resto de la pagina ?

Answer (score 1):

Una posibilidad sería usar el [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (o `sessionStorage`, dependiendo de cuánto quieres que se conserven los datos) para guardar una variable que indique si el botón de MANUAL se ha pulsado. Si esa variable del localStorage se ha inicializado, entonces se llamaría a la función `mostrar` para que se muestre el elemento #alerta.

Para eso, tendrías que cambiar el JavaScript para que se guarde esa variable, que se compararía al principio. Esto se haría así (con comentarios):

```
function mostrar() {
  var x = document.getElementById('alerta');
  // he cambiado la manera de comprobar el estilo a `getComputedStyle` que te 
  // permite ver estilos que vienen de CSS, de lo contrario, la primera vez
  // siempre se irá por el `else` porque el CSS no estaba inline
  if (getComputedStyle(x, null).display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
    // guardamos una variable en el localStorage (el valor es irrelevante)
    localStorage.setItem('alertavisible', '1');
  } else { 
    x.style.display = 'none';
    // quitamos la variable del localstorage
    localStorage.removeItem('alertavisible');
  }
  // esto dará un error si la variable está en el localstorage, pero no importará al estar al final de la función
  event.preventDefault();
}

// cuando se cargue la función, comprobamos si la variable existe en el localstorage y
// ejecutamos `mostrar` si existe
if (localStorage.getItem('alertavisible')) { mostrar(); }
```

Y se vería todo así (aunque no funciona aquí porque `localStorage` no se permite por razones de seguridad):

```js
function mostrar() {
  var x = document.getElementById('alerta');
  if (getComputedStyle(x, null).display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
    localStorage.setItem('alertavisible', '1');
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
    localStorage.removeItem('alertavisible');
  }
  event.preventDefault();
}

if (localStorage.getItem('alertavisible')) { mostrar(); }
```

```css
#alerta {
  margin-top: 1 0px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="alerta">
    <a href="Start.htm">aparece con el  submit MANUAL</a><br>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="MANUAL">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" value="MANUAL" onclick="mostrar()">
    <input type="hidden" name='"MANUAL"' size="20px" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name='"AUTOMATICO"' size="20px" value="0">
  </form>
</div>
<td width="144px" height="21px">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" value="AUTOMATICO">
    <input type="hidden" name='"AUTOMATICO"' size="20px" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name='"MANUAL"' size="20px" value="0">
  </form>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola espero te sirva mi aportacion, veo que tienes 2 formularios, asi que hice 2 eventos, uno por cada formulario, llame al elemento y solo añadi la funcion display none, para ocultar y display block para mostrar

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="alerta">
            <a href="Start.htm">aparece con el  submit MANUAL</a><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="MANUAL">
        <form id="manual" method="post" action="">
            <input type="submit" value="MANUAL">
            <input type="hidden" name='"MANUAL"' size="20px" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name='"AUTOMATICO"' size="20px" value="0">
        </form>
    </div>
    <td width="144px" height="21px">
        <form id="auto" method="post" action="">
            <input type="submit" value="AUTOMATICO">
            <input type="hidden" name='"AUTOMATICO"' size="20px" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name='"MANUAL"' size="20px" value="0">
        </form>
    </td>
</body>
<style>
    #alerta {
        margin-top: 1 0px;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    #wrapper {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<script>
    const formManual = document.getElementById('manual')
    const formAuto = document.getElementById('auto')
    const alerta = document.getElementById('alerta')
    formAuto.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        alerta.style.display = 'none'
    })
    formManual.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        alerta.style.display = 'block'
    })
</script>

</html>
```